# Sorting by the values of a sub-dictionary and then by primary keys

Tags: sorting, python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

This code gives the output that I want. What I want to know is if there's a more effective way to get the same output. It seems like I'm taking the scenic route on this one. For this example, I'm printing out the results, my real data is written to a text file.

```
# using a dict with a sub-dict as its values, sort, format, and print out as delimited output suitable to import into Excel

tmpList = []

dict_1 = {'key_b1': {'val3': 'val_b3', 'val1': 'val_b1', 'val2': 'val_b2'}, 'key_a1': {'val3': 'val_a3', 'val1': 'val_a1', 'val2': 'val_a2'}, 'key_e1': {'val3': 'val_e3', 'val1': 'val_e1', 'val2': 'val_e2'}, 'key_d1': {'val3': 'val_d3', 'val1': 'val_d1', 'val2': 'val_d2'}, 'key_c1': {'val3': 'val_c3', 'val1': 'val_c1', 'val2': 'val_c2'}}

"""
# same dictionary as above but formatted for readability
dict_1 =
{
'key_b1': {'val3': 'val_b3', 'val1': 'val_b1', 'val2': 'val_b2'},
'key_a1': {'val3': 'val_a3', 'val1': 'val_a1', 'val2': 'val_a2'},
'key_e1': {'val3': 'val_e3', 'val1': 'val_e1', 'val2': 'val_e2'},
'key_d1': {'val3': 'val_d3', 'val1': 'val_d1', 'val2': 'val_d2'},
'key_c1': {'val3': 'val_c3', 'val1': 'val_c1', 'val2': 'val_c2'}
}
"""

# turn dictionary into a list with sublists
for k, v in dict_1.iteritems():
    tmpList.append([k, [v.values()[0], v.values()[1], v.values()[2]]])
print tmpList, '\n\n'
"""
# result of turning dict_1 into a list with sublists, only printed for those that might need some insight
[
['key_e1', ['val_e3', 'val_e2', 'val_e1']],
['key_b1', ['val_b3', 'val_b2', 'val_b1']],
['key_d1', ['val_d3', 'val_d2', 'val_d1']],
['key_a1', ['val_a3', 'val_a2', 'val_a1']],
['key_c1', ['val_c3', 'val_c2', 'val_c1']]
]
"""

# sort each sublist by members, and then sort by outer members
sort_sublists = [[k, sorted(l)] for k, l in tmpList]
sort_outer_lists = sorted(sort_sublists)

# print out in a comma delimited format
for d in sort_outer_lists:
    print d[0] + ',' + d[1][0] + ',' + d[1][1] + ',' + d[1][2]

"""
# final desired results
key_a1,val_a1,val_a2,val_a3
key_b1,val_b1,val_b2,val_b3
key_c1,val_c1,val_c2,val_c3
key_d1,val_d1,val_d2,val_d3
key_e1,val_e1,val_e2,val_e3
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension?

```
[[k, v.values()] for k, v in dict_1.iteritems()]
```

It seems to do what you want

```
>>> [[k, v.values()] for k, v in dict_1.iteritems()] 
[
 ['key_e1', ['val_e3', 'val_e2', 'val_e1']],
 ['key_b1', ['val_b3', 'val_b2', 'val_b1']],
 ['key_d1', ['val_d3', 'val_d2', 'val_d1']],
 ['key_a1', ['val_a3', 'val_a2', 'val_a1']],
 ['key_c1', ['val_c3', 'val_c2', 'val_c1']]
]
```

Edit: To sort the inner list values and the outer lists by the dictionary key you could use the built in sorted() function. For example

```
>>> sorted([[k, sorted(v.values())] for k, v in dict_1.iteritems()]) 
    [
     ['key_a1', ['val_a1', 'val_a2', 'val_a3']],
     ['key_b1', ['val_b1', 'val_b2', 'val_b3']],
     ['key_c1', ['val_c1', 'val_c2', 'val_c3']],
     ['key_d1', ['val_d1', 'val_d2', 'val_d3']],
     ['key_e1', ['val_e1', 'val_e2', 'val_e3']]
    ]
```

Comment: Hmmmmm... that could replace running dict_1 through a for-loop, then I could use the two sorting routines I wrote. That's a little bit shorter.

Comment: which part of the list do you need to sort? the list of dictionary values or the keys?

Comment: Both, first by the members of each sublist, then by the outer members which would be the dictionary primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using python 2.7 or later, you can use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict%20%22OrderedDict). It's part of the collections module and remembers its insertion order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> dict_1 = {'key_b1': {'val3': 'val_b3', 'val1': 'val_b1', 'val2': 'val_b2'}, 'key_a1': {'val3': 'val_a3', 'val1': 'val_a1', 'val2': 'val_a2'}, 'key_e1': {'val3': 'val_e3', 'val1': 'val_e1', 'val2': 'val_e2'}, 'key_d1': {'val3': 'val_d3', 'val1': 'val_d1', 'val2': 'val_d2'}, 'key_c1': {'val3': 'val_c3', 'val1': 'val_c1', 'val2': 'val_c2'}}
>>> for k in sorted(dict_1.keys()):
...    d[k]=OrderedDict(sorted(dict_1[k].items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
...
>>> print '\n'.join([item[0]+','+','.join(item[1]) for item in d.items()])
key_a1,val1,val2,val3
key_b1,val1,val2,val3
key_c1,val1,val2,val3
key_d1,val1,val2,val3
key_e1,val1,val2,val3
>>>
```

Comment: That sorts the members of each sublist, that is the data prefixed with 'val' for a representation of a dictionary value, but not the data prefixed with 'key' (the original dictionary primary keys). At least that's what I got.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `d = OrderedDict()` line